# Where is $g(x)=x\lfloor x+1 \rfloor$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, continuity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Determine the points of continuity of $$g(x)=x\lfloor x+1 \rfloor$$

---

I know the point of continuity of $f(x)=\lfloor x+1 \rfloor$ are $x \in (a,a+1)$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. But how do I determine the points of continuity of $x\lfloor x+1 \rfloor$? One idea I have is to consider the graph of $x(x+1)$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The points of continuity of $f(x)$ is not what you have currently written in your post.

Comment: Hint: Let $n\in\mathbb Z$. Consider one-sided limits $\lim_{x\to n-}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to n+}g(x)$, which you can explicitly calculate. Prove they are equal to each other if and only if $n=0$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer pardon me, but isn't floor function discontinuous at every integer point?

Comment: @Ellie_Wong Sure, but you have incorrectly translated that from English to the mathematical language. (Your $b$ has got to be $a+1$.)

Comment: @Ellie_Wong careful. Take $b=3$ and $a=1$,  then $2\in (a,b)$ .

Comment: You're right, @Ellie_Wong, but then you've got to write $(a,b) \setminus \mathbb Z$. Now you can take on the hint in the second comment.

Comment: @StinkingBishop thanks. I have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;a\in\Bbb Z\,.$

Since $\;\lfloor x+1\rfloor=\begin{cases}a&\text{for any }\;x\in[a-1,a)\\a+1&\text{for any }\;x\in[a,a+1)\quad,\end{cases}$

it follows that

$\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-} x\lfloor x+1\rfloor=a^2\;\;$ and

$\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-} x\lfloor x+1\rfloor=a(a+1)=g(a)\;.$

On the other hand,

$a^2=a(a+1)\;$ if only if $\;a=0\;,\;$ consequently,

the only point of continuity of the function $\,g(x)\,$ which belongs to $\,\Bbb Z\,,\;$ is $\,a=0\,.$

Moreover, in any point $\;x_0\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z\,,\,$ the function $\,g(x)\,$ is continuous because both $\,\varphi(x)=x\,$ and $\,\psi(x)=\lfloor x+1\rfloor\,$ are continuous in $\,x_0\,,$ indeed $\;x_0\in\big(\lfloor x_0\rfloor,\lfloor x_0\rfloor+1\big)$ and $\;\psi(x)=\lfloor x+1\rfloor=\lfloor x_0\rfloor+1\;$ is a constant function on the interval $\big(\lfloor x_0\rfloor,\lfloor x_0\rfloor+1\big).$

Hence the function $\,g(x)\,$ is continuous on $\big(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z\big)\cup\big\{0\big\}.$

Answer (score 0):

Case.(1) $x\in [n+\delta,n+1-\delta]$, $g(x)=x\cdot(n+1)$, so $g$ is continous inside each invertal.

Case.(2) at each integer point $n$,

$$\lim_{x\to n^+}g(x)=n(n+1),~~~\lim_{x\to n^-}g(x)=n\cdot n$$

therefore,

$$\lim_{x\to n^+}g(x)=\lim_{x\to n^-}g(x)\Longleftrightarrow n=0$$

Namely, $g$ is continuous at $n=0$, and discontinuous at other integer points $n\neq0$

Here is a plot for function $g$
[image]